# overflow-y: scroll appears when amount of items in list become more than 5 in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to make scroll bar appear on the side of div when i get more than 5 items added to chip-list. Chip-list div:

```
 <div class="col-7 container w-100 koostaja-choosen fixed-height" >
      <mat-chip-list  #koostajaChipList>
        <span *ngFor="let koostaja of koostamiseForm.get('koostajad').value">
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let profiil of koostaja.profiilList"
                    [selectable]="false"
                    [removable]="true"
                    (removed)="removeKoostaja(profiil, koostamiseForm)"
                    class="font-size-14px"
                    matTooltip="{{profiil.kohtuuksusLuhend}} {{profiil.ametikohaNimetus}}">
                    {{koostaja.eesnimi}} {{koostaja.perenimi}}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="!isDokumentJoustanud">cancel</mat-icon>
          </mat-chip>
        </span>
        <mat-error *ngIf="koostamiseForm.get('koostajad')?.errors?.required">Koostaja on vaja lisada!</mat-error>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </div>
```

and here is my css :

```
.koostaja-choosen {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 12px
}

.overflow-y-visible {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

i tried add to my div

```
[ngClass]="{'overflow-y-visible': koostamiseForm.get('koostajad').value.length > 5}" but it doesnt work.
```

thanks for any advice

Comment: Is there a reason why `overflow-y: auto;` doesn't work on `.koostaja-choosen`?

Comment: Did you try adding `overflow-y: auto !important;` to the `koostaja-choosen` class instead?

Comment: remove overflow-y: hidden from the `.koostaja-choosen` class in your CSS, as the [ngClass] will dynamically toggle the `overflow-y-visible` class based on the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use **overflow-y:auto;** instead **overflow-y:scroll;** this will work as required.